# How to derive a column based on a filtered pandas dataframe with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
import easygui as gui
import pandas as pd
filename = gui.fileopenbox(msg='Please choose the Excel workbook containing the bank data.') #select workbook containing FC and WF data
colnames=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'] #define col names because variable number of col won't read unless max col# is defined
dfdata = pd.read_csv(filename,names=colnames) #set dataframe equal to csv file
key = dfdata["12"].isnull() #set criteria for splitting data equal to null value in column 12
dftopdata = dfdata.loc[key] #set new df equal to key criteria
dfbottomdata = dfdata.loc[~key] #set new df NOT equal to key criteria
dftopdata = dftopdata.dropna(axis=1, how='all', thresh=None, subset=None) #drop any column with all values = NaN
dftopdata = dftopdata.dropna(axis=0, how='all', thresh=None, subset=None) #drop any row with all values = NaN
header = dftopdata.iloc[1] #Creates a header variable at row index location 1
dftopdata = dftopdata[2:] #Resets dataframe equal to row 2 and beyond
dftopdata.rename(columns = header, inplace = True) #sets names of columns in the dataframe equal to header
header = dfbottomdata.iloc[0] #Creates a header variable at row index location 0
dfbottomdata = dfbottomdata[1:] #Resets dataframe equal to row 1 and beyond
dfbottomdata.rename(columns = header, inplace = True) #sets names of columns in the dataframe equal to header
```

The above code results in two data frames.

This is a sample of data from the data frame called top data:

```
Routing        Currency  Account Number  Account Name  Opening Ledger  Credits Amt  Credits Num  Debits Amt  Debits Num  Closing Ledger 
123456789      USD       1111111112      A             717.57          100.00       1            100.72      3           716.85         
123456789      USD       1111111113      B             1,350.30        NaN          0            28.53       1           1,321.77       
123456789      USD       1111111114      C             26,570.34       320.52       1            42.17       1           26,848.69      
123456789      USD       1111111115      D             1,031.95        2,000.00     1            703.95      2           2,328.00       
123456789      USD       1111111116      E             1,000.00        600.00       2            72.03       2           1,527.97
```

And this is a sample of data from the data frame called bottom data:

```
Date        Routing        Currency  Account Number  Account Name  BAI Type            BAI Code  CR Amount  DB Amount  Serial Num  Ref Num   Description                                       
12/10/2019  123456789      USD       1111111112      A             Miscellaneous Fees  7         NaN        28.69      NaN         69650977  MTHLY ANALYSIS CHARGE                             
12/20/2019  123456789      USD       1111111112      A             Misc Credit         1         100        NaN        NaN         70069250  XFR TO DDA FR DDA 001111085716122019RF#1452300... 
12/24/2019  123456789      USD       1111111112      A             Misc Debit          4         NaN        69.08      NaN         70184768  ACCESSIBLEINSURA WEBPAYMENTPCOF PROPERTIES SERIES 
12/24/2019  123456789      USD       1111111112      A             Misc Debit          5         NaN        2.95       NaN         70184769  SEP INSURANC ACH WEBPAYMENTPCOF PROPERTIES SERIES 
12/10/2019  123456789      USD       1111111113      B             Miscellaneous Fees  6         NaN        28.53      NaN         69645166  MTHLY ANALYSIS CHARGE
```

I'd like to add a new column called "Balance" to the bottom data df that contains the balance of each bank account.

The balance for the earliest transaction date of a given bank account in the bottom data df should be equal to the opening ledger value for that bank account in the first data frame plus any credits or minus any debits in that row of the bottom data df.

Each subsequent transaction for the given bank account should equal the balance from previous transaction date plus any credits or minus any debits in that row of the bottom data df.

This is how I'd like the bottom data df to look after analysis:

```
    Date        Routing        Currency  Account Number  Account Name  BAI Type            BAI Code  CR Amount  DB Amount  Serial Num  Ref Num   Description                                        Balance           
    12/10/2019  123456789      USD       1111111112      A             Miscellaneous Fees  7         NaN        28.69      NaN         69650977  MTHLY ANALYSIS CHARGE                              688.88            
    12/20/2019  123456789      USD       1111111112      A             Misc Credit         1         100        NaN        NaN         70069250  XFR TO DDA FR DDA 001111085716122019RF#1452300...  788.88            
    12/24/2019  123456789      USD       1111111112      A             Misc Debit          4         NaN        69.08      NaN         70184768  ACCESSIBLEINSURA WEBPAYMENTPCOF PROPERTIES SERIES  719.80            
    12/24/2019  123456789      USD       1111111112      A             Misc Debit          5         NaN        2.95       NaN         70184769  SEP INSURANC ACH WEBPAYMENTPCOF PROPERTIES SERIES  716.85            
    12/10/2019  123456789      USD       1111111113      B             Miscellaneous Fees  6         NaN        28.53      NaN         69645166  MTHLY ANALYSIS CHARGE                              1321.77
```

But I'm stumped as to what to do next.

I've thought about creating a data frame for each bank account but that seems inefficient.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please edit your sample data into the _text_ of your question, not as an image, to make a [mcve] that we can repreduce

Comment: can you supply an expected output dataframe

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this, exactly? You cannot expect other people to do everything for you, right?

Comment: I've tried to address all of your comments. Let me know if I can further clarify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `dfbottomdata` is sorted ascending (least to most) values for `Date`, `Routing`, and `Account Number`, then the below code should work:

```py
#Add Closing Ledger value from dftopdata
dfbottomdata = dfbottomdata.merge(dftopdata[['Routing','Account Number','Opening Ledger']], on=['Routing','Account Number'])
dfbottomdata.rename(columns={'Opening Ledger': 'Balance'}, inplace=True)

#Replace NaN with 0 for calculations
dfbottomdata['CR Amount'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
dfbottomdata['DB Amount'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

#Handle use case for first row
dfbottomdata.loc[0, 'Balance'] = dfbottomdata.loc[0, 'Balance'] + dfbottomdata.loc[0, 'CR Amount'] - dfbottomdata.loc[0, 'DB Amount']

#Iterate through each row, applying logic only if previous row Routing/AccountNumber match
for i in range(1, len(dfbottomdata)):
    if (dfbottomdata.loc[i-1, 'Routing'] == dfbottomdata.loc[i, 'Routing']) & (dfbottomdata.loc[i-1, 'Account Number'] == dfbottomdata.loc[i, 'Account Number']):
        dfbottomdata.loc[i, 'Balance'] = dfbottomdata.loc[i-1, 'Balance'] + dfbottomdata.loc[i, 'CR Amount'] - dfbottomdata.loc[i, 'DB Amount']
    else:
        dfbottomdata.loc[i, 'Balance'] = dfbottomdata.loc[i, 'Balance'] + dfbottomdata.loc[i, 'CR Amount'] - dfbottomdata.loc[i, 'DB Amount']
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I'm working through it now to see if it accomplishes what I need it to do. I'll mark as answered if so or provide clarifications if it doesn't quite do what I was hoping it would.

Comment: It worked! The only thing I needed to change in your answer was Closing Ledger to Opening Ledger. Thanks!